# Java Web Start / draggable applet

Tags: java, applet, draggable, java-web-start

I'm trying to get an applet to persist after the browser closes, in order to finish a process before quitting.

If I give the applet the 'draggable' attribute then drag it outside of the browser page the applet is still available via LiveConnect from javascript AND it continues after the browser is closed.

But I would like a way to achieve this without the user having to drag the applet outside the browser each time.

Starting the applet directly using JWS does not let me communicate with it from javascript which is necessary for my application.

Is anyone aware of a means of achieving this ?

Comment: What is the JS used for, and is it used in the 'finish a process'?  It seems it it needs JS for that, and is disconnected from the browser, you're screwed.  BTW - What exactly is done in this 'process' and why can it not be called from `destroy()`?

Comment: @AndrewThompson The applet uploads a file to the server. The javascript is not needed once the applet starts the upload. However closing the browser once the upload has started should not terminate the upload, hence the 'process must finish'. I don't think I can block long enough in the destroy method to achieve this (It would seem there is only a 200ms delay for shutting down in the new plug in).

Answer (score 1):

How about pop up your window from the applet, and use javascript to monitor the browser closing event, and return false when applet is not ready?

Comment: You cannot stop a using closing the browser - only ask them to confirm the action. Hence the desire for an applet that has been 'dragged' out of the browser. I cant find a mechanism that works to do this so I will probably end up with a java web start application that listens as a web server - I can then talk to it from the browser via local ajax http calls.